# How to implement speaker on and off functionality like whatsapp or any calling app using android?

Tags: android

I am developing one app in which call functionality also available but when i want to add speaker on and speaker off functionality like Whatsapp while making calls. can anyone tell me how to achieve this in android. thanks in advance.

```
speakerOn.setOnClickListener {
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL)
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
    mediaPlayer.start()
} 

speakerOff.setOnClickListener {
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    mediaPlayer.isLooping
}
```

Comment: try to post some code, so that we can see what you are using to do this functionality and whats the problem??

Comment: i want to add functionality like whats App speaker on and off while making call so that i can talk with other whether my speaker is on or off? are you getting my point?

Comment: I already understood your point, but you have to show some of your code because we don't know what you are using for audio or how your calling works, at least show that how audio is being working in call

Comment: speakerOn.setOnClickListener {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL)
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }

        speakerOff.setOnClickListener {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
            mediaPlayer.isLooping
        }

Comment: these are the two buttons. On  button one  i want to play audio in EarPiece and on button click i want to play audio using speaker.

Comment: may be this will work for you: `audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(true/false);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true/false);`